# Coger nombre de la colección desde .yml MongoDB Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Tengo un problema en mi proyecto de Spring Boot y es que necesito que el nombre de la colección de MongoDB que le quiero asignar a una clase tiene que venir desde el archivo .yml.

Actualmente la parte de MongoDB de mi archivo .yml es la siguiente:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: nombreUsuario
      password: passUsuario
      authentication-database: adnmin
      database: test
      collection: coleccion
```

Y mi clase modelo para crear los objetos que quiero guardar es esta:

```
@Document(collection = "${spring.data.mongodb.collection}")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Component
public class RegistroMongo {

    @Id
    private String userUid;
}
```

No puedo lanzar la aplicación porque dice que no existe la base de datos test con la colección `${spring.data.mongodb.password}`, y es que toma este dato como un literal.

Como puedo hacer para que obtenga el valor desde el archivo de configuración como si fuera un `@Value="${spring.data.mongodb.password}"`?